# How to my toggle button change color only my collapse is opened in my bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When we open collapse, button change color. but when we closed collapse by button click, the button doesn't return to its initial color. Button is focused. And I want that lost the focus.

I have tried with css :focus, but it didn´t lose focus after collapse have been closed by button.
I think that jquery function is necessary, although I've tried, my js skills shouldn't be sufficient.

I need help please

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/Hg4Ts/4/)

My Html code:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>

</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.wrapper {width:100%, height:100%;}
```

My jQuery function:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    function CloseNav() {
        $(".navbar-collapse").stop().animate({'height': 0},300, function () {
            $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in').addClass("collapse");
        });
        $(".navbar-toggle").stop().removeClass('collapsed');
    }

    $('html').click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
            CloseNav();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: But it's changing .... you mean not change on hover? just after click?

Comment: Not change after click for close collapse in toggle-button

Comment: you again :) , may you clarify it here?

Comment: it doesn't even in bootstrap website it self http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: when we open collapse, button change color. but when we closed collapse by button click, the button doesn't return to its initial color. Button is focused. And I want that lost the focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi the problem here is with the `focus` state of the button once you click it never loses the focus unless you click outside again. You can try this:

First make a class that replicates the `hover` and `focus` state for the button:

```
.highlight {background:#ddd}
```

Then you can modify your Jquery to force the button lose his focus state on `click` and apply the class to keep the visual effect:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight').blur();
});
```

Also since your collapse close every time you click outside the button you need to add some there:

```
if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
     $('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('highlight'); /**Add This**/
     CloseNav();
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4Ts/7/)**

Comment: Thank you. Even this is! Cheeers! :)

Comment: Np mate glad to help you

Comment: It's a CSS issue with the button and could be fixed in bootstrap way without jQuery

Comment: @hsobhy that's why you downvote me? If you look well with your solution you still get the focus state after the click. Still have the border around and isn't recommendable to get that border out for usability. Since OP is already using Jquery is a good solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. I really learn here every post. for the border it still CSS possible change issue.

Comment: It´s solution is best. But with alterations on classes in html, because with button´s stripes click had a bug. I solved this and works perfectly. Thanks dudes

Answer (score 3):

Try this CSS ...  a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4Ts/16/)

```
.navbar-default button.navbar-toggle.collapsed:focus,
.navbar-default button.navbar-toggle.collapsed{ background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
}
.navbar-default button.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default button.navbar-toggle.collapsed:hover{ background-color:#ddd;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It´s the best way for my problem! Cheeers! :)

Comment: you welcome .. will continue untill you finish .. keep posting :)

Comment: @user3216077  If you look well with this solution you still get the focus state after the click. Still have the border around and isn't recommendable to get that border out for usability.

Comment: This solution had one bug, after close collpase with button, the button:hover was disable, becousa de nem focus is active. For this the Danko´s soultion is best. But with alterations on classes in html, because with button´s stripes click had a bug. Thanks dudes :)

Comment: just add .navbar-default button.navbar-toggle.collapsed:hover to the second case .. I've updated the code both JS and CSS http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4Ts/16/show/ ... code http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4Ts/16/

Comment: the last one also don't add any styles from JS and keep the original styling and border as it when close the button or click the body